# If 2 electrons are entangled $[a] [b]$. if we throw a photon at $-[a]$ will it come out of $[b]-$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

i was confused as to what will happen when two electrons which are entangled and then if one is exposed to light. will the absorption and emission theory still work and if so how will it work in this case?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To have quantum entanglement one has to have a definite solution of the quantum mechanical equations describing the entangled system, i.e. a single wavefunction.

At the level of electrons it is photons that interact electromagnetically. But every new interaction requires a new  quantum mechanical solution. If your two entangled electrons are flying apart, and a photon interacts with one, the entangled solution is no longer valid, a new wavefunction will describe the photon-electron state, the other electron going on its way.

If you mean the classical light  absorption and emission theory, it cannot apply to single electrons.

Comment: "a new wavefunction will describe the photon-electron state, the other electron going on its way."
This is wrong. If A and B are entangled, and A and C interact, in general the result will be three-particle with some entanglement between A and B.

Answer (score 0):

If the two electrons only have their spins entangled (which is what we usually mean by entangled particles), then no. The interaction will be localized at the position of $a$. To see that the photon's target was part of an entangled pair, you would probably need to repeat the experiment many times and collect statistics on the spins of the final state.

If the original electrons had their positions entangled instead, there would be no way to throw the photon at $a$ but not $b$.